# Certain math symbols & font combinations break XeLaTeX in TexLive 2021

Tags: xetex, overleaf, computer-modern

The following MWE compiles fine with XeLaTeX and TeXLive 2020:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathspec}
    \setallmainfonts[Mapping=tex-text]{Carlito}
    \setmathsfont(Greek){[cmmi10]}

\begin{document}

Hello world. $\mu$

\end{document}
```

The text uses the open font Carlito, though the math uses Computer Modern.

This MWE fails to render (at least, in Overleaf) when I switch to use TeXLive 2021. No error messages appear in the log, as best as I can tell; Overleaf just says "PDF Rendering Error".

Commenting out the line `\setmathsfont(Greek){[cmmi10]}` allows the document to compile, though the `$\mu$` symbol is now in the Carlito font, which I didn't want.

What happened between TeXLive 2020 & 2021? Is there a new way to reference the old Computer Modern font?

Comment: Works fine for me with a local TeX Live 2022. Contact OL support?

Comment: It works for me locally in texlive 2021 and 2022, contact overleaf support

Comment: I can reproduce the problem on Overleaf. It only happens with TeXLive 2021, older versions on Overleaf work fine, just like the OP said. The generated PDF is broken and cannot be opened.

Comment: Have contacted Overleaf support. Will post comment of their reply when it comes. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Overleaf support says:

> I believe this is caused by a slightly different package version in
> use in our TeX Live 2021 image (which hasn't changed since we released
> it last year), compared to a local TeX Live 2021 installation. The
> problem should be fixed when we release our TeX Live 2022 image in the
> coming months. Until then, I'd recommend using Overleaf's TeX Live
> 2020 image for any projects affected by this.

In my case, TeX Live 2020 works just fine.

Comment: If possible, could you tick this answer as correct (if it is and it does look so from my view) so the `community` bot doesn't bump this to the top of the feed please :)